# Call a function from an object : object.function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, methods

How can I call a function from an object in javascript, like for example in jquery you call myDiv.html() to get the html of that div.

So what I want is this to work :

```
function bar(){
 return this.html();
}

alert($('#foo').bar());
```

this is a simplified example, so please don't say : just do $('#foo').html() :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    bar: function() {
        return this.html();
    }
});

alert($('#foo').bar());
```

Answer (score 5):

You mean how you call a function with an *object in context*?

This works-

```
function bar() {
    return this.html();
}

bar.apply($('#foo'));
```

Or if you want to attach a method to an object permanently,

```
obj = {x: 1};
obj.prototype.bar = function() {return this.x;};
obj.bar();
```

Comment: Clean and (most important) library agnostic. +1

Comment: However, in this context (not to abuse the word), the call method would be more apropos vs. apply.

Comment: permanently => (in the above answer) meant to mean, if you want all objects to inherit that method in it's original context, use the prototype property to assign a new method to an object.

Answer (score -1):

To add a `getHtml` function to a `div` element with the id `foo` you could do this:
`$("#foo")[0].getHtml = function () {
  return this.innerHTML;
};
alert($("#foo")[0].getHtml());`

If this is not what you wanted, but rather extend jQuery, you should have a look at the post by Alex Barrett.